# Share video using Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to share a youtube video in `iOS` using `Facebook-SDK` but it always return `error code 2`

> invalid value for videoURL

**Here is my code**

```
NSURL *videoURL =[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://youtu.be/i-QlMqZh8_g"];
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content =[[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc]init];
content.video= [FBSDKShareVideo videoWithVideoURL:videoURL];
[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

Comment: NSURL is not like the URL that you type into your browser.  Think of it more like a filepath to a piece of data on your iOS device.  You can read more about NSURL [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/).  Like Victor Lins said, you'll need to share the youtube link as a `FBSDKShareLinkContent` not a `FBSDKShareVideoContent`.

Answer (score 2):

To share the youtube link:

```
NSURL *videoURL =[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://youtu.be/i-QlMqZh8_g"];

FBSDKShareLinkContent *shareLinkContent = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
shareLinkContent.contentURL = videoURL;

[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:shareLinkContent delegate:self];
```